# Migration from DynamoDB to Spanner/BigTable

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-spanner

I have a use case where I need to migrate 70 TB of data from DynamoDB to BigTable and Spanner. Tables with a single index will go to BigTable else they will go to Spanner.

I can easily handle the historical loads by exporting the data to S3 --> GCS --> Spanner/BigTable. But the challenging part is to handle the incremental streaming loads simultaneously happening on DynamoDB. There are 300 tables in DynamoDB.

How to handle this thing in the best possible manner? Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 5):

One approach could be done using lambdas to capture the dynamodb changes, posting the changes to GCP pub/sub, and then having a Dataflow streaming pipeline processing the incoming pub/sub messages, writing it to Spanner or BigTable depending on the table

The basic DynamoDB->Spanner solution is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-dynamodb-to-cloud-spanner

This could be adapted to handle the different destinations for different tables.